# Can I specify the encoding of a sourced file?

Tags: unicode

When vim sources a file (`vimrc`, or `:so ...`), how does it know in what encoding the file was written? Can I specify the encoding with which it should source the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vim has a built-in option for that:

```
'encoding'
```

It's by default "latin1" or the value of the environment variable `$LANG` (e.g. in my case `:echo $LANG` returns `en_US.UTF-8`).

The value of encoding is derived from `$LANG`, not taken verbatim. `en_US.UTF-8` would give you `utf-8`. (credits to @romainl)

You can control this value like any other option in vim:

```
set encoding=...
```

Please note that in the case of your `vimrc`, you cannot take advantage of the modeline for setting this option. As said in the doc:

```
This option cannot be set from a modeline.  It would most likely
corrupt the text.
```

You can also have a look at the different encoding options proposed in Vim:

- `:h scriptencoding`
- `:h 'encoding'`
- `:h 'fileencoding'`
- `:h 'termencoding'`

Comment: Note that the value of `encoding` is *derived* from `$LANG`, not taken verbatim. `en_US.UTF-8` would give you `utf-8`.

Comment: Setting encoding is the wrong way, it will possibly invalidate all your registers and all variables holding strings. The correct way is to use the :scriptencoding command.